# My fast track U.K. student visa is late without any letter of explanation?

Tags: visas, uk, application-status

I paid for the fast track 5 day service. My case was a bit complicated due to previous immigration history  I’m from a low risk country and did not need any interview or much evidence for my files.

I have received no contact to explain why the visa is running late and today is the 7th day. It says clearly on gov U.K. website that it takes 5 days and if they’ll take longer they will email you to explain why. Anything I can do about this? I need my visa ASAP.

Comment: Might the promised time have been five working days, rather than five days?

Comment: @David it's definitely working days

Comment: @Anonymous All you can do is contact UKVI if you don’t hear anything by the end of the promised 5 working days https://www.gov.uk/contact-ukvi-inside-outside-uk

Comment: Yes, it is working days. We’re on the 7th working day now. I can contact UKVI but they don’t provide case specific information so I don’t think there’s a point in calling them. Anything else I can do? I’m just confused why no letter has been given to me when it’s beem over the 5 days promised on the website.

Comment: What does "My case was a bit complicated due to previous immigration history" mean?

Comment: Previous visa rejections on a different tier due to mishaps by the solicitor regarding paperwork and timing of applications. Included all immigration history as accurately as possible to speed up the process but because there is history, I understand it can take longer than a straight forward application. Just don’t know why I’m not being contacted regarding why it’s late.

Comment: Hmm. At some stage the web site should have advised you against buying priority service if you have adverse immigration history. I would not expect this to be processed in the normal timeframe, let alone the fast track timeframe.

Comment: VFS does say complicated cases may not be processed in the fast track time. Gov U.K. doesn’t advise against it. They tell you that if there’s any issues that will slow down the process, they will contact you within the 5 days to tell you it won’t be processed within the allocated time and that no refund for the fast track service will be given. That’s fine, I agreed to that, but I just need to know why I haven’t been contacted.